# Limitations of getFiles and getDirectories when reachs file/folder the user has no access permissions

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there any workaround for dealing with the limitation of getFiles and getDirectories to return the content even if they reachs a access denied file/folder?

How can I make then return the filesystem tree with all files/folders a user has access permissions at least for reading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple implementations of this. Basically, you can't use the default one because it will throw an exception and stop when a user has insufficient permissions. I usually see people list all the directories, and then try each one and catch any exceptions.

[Recursive File Search in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437728/recursive-file-search-in-net)

Comment: I have implemented with Recursive File Search and the problem still persist. I found a way just enabling users to use the first level folder from a Logical Drive.... Thanks